# Item count behavior in table title

Tags: tables, title

I have item count in table title that show all data count in system like this 
[image]

But when user filter date and only have 7 data count on this. Should item count in table show only 7 or have another pattern ?
[image: Item count after use filter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that needs a careful balance and I would say, "it depends".

With your typical RDBMS, it is going to be quite a bit slower to fetch all applicable results and then filter (thus giving you access to both total invoice count and filtered invoice count) than to just get the filtered invoices directly.

If your search algorithm is not particularly fast, I would suggest that many users would prefer the faster search and not see the total number of invoices.

You can compromise to some degree by changing the wording from "{x} invoices" too - "{x} relevant invoices found" implicitly suggests that there are additional irrelevant invoices in the system. An alternative phrasing which completley removes any implication either way is to simply say "{x} results".

Answer (score 0):

When designing tables with selection and filters I have used the pattern "7 of 300". I think this would work ok here.

[image: balsamiq image showing table with the 1 of counter in filtered and unfiltered mode]

P.s. I am not entirely decided how the selection check box should be shown in the filtered view. It should either show as checked as in the whole set in this view is currently selected. Or in the semi selected state as I have it in the lower diagram where the state refers to the selection across whole set.

But maybe that is a whole different discussion - as you do not have checkboxes in your design.